# GLR parsing algorithm resources

Tags: compiler-construction, parsing, parser-generator, glr

[I am writing](http://www.codegrunt.co.uk/terse-lang/blog/?p=91) a [GLR parser generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glr_parser) and would like some advice on resources relating to this algorithm both on the internet and of the dead-tree variety (books for those unfamiliar with the geek-speak).

I know Bison can generate GLR parsers, and given it's under the GPL I can examine its code, however it'd be nice to have a full description of the algorithm.

So, does anybody know of any good resources out there which I can make use of? Thanks.

Comment: Very cool project (Terse, not the parser generator), I’ll follow its progress with interest.

Comment: Unfortunately I've been distracted by many things, so the project has stalled but... more work will commence on it soon promise!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some good stuff I've come across before online:

- a paper about [Elkhound](http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/), another open source GLR parser: Scott McPeak, George C. Necula.  [Elkhound: A Fast, Practical GLR Parser Generator](http://scottmcpeak.com/papers/elkhound_cc04.ps).  In Proceedings of Conference on Compiler Constructor (CC04), April 2004.

and for more detail:

- the [UCB/CSSD-2-1214 technical report](http://scottmcpeak.com/papers/elkhound_tr.ps), which is an expanded version of the above paper;
- the paper referenced in the [Bison documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Generalized-LR-Parsing.html): Elizabeth Scott, Adrian Johnstone and Shamsa Sadaf Hussain. [Tomita-Style Generalised LR Parsers](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/research/languages/publications/tomita_style_1.ps).  TR-00-12, Royal Holloway, University of London, Department of Computer Science, December 2000.

And I know of a third open source GLR parser: [DParser](http://dparser.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 6):

Adrian Johnstone publishes a lot of work on advanced versions of GLR algorithms.  His [publications website](http://pure.rhul.ac.uk/portal/en/persons/adrian-johnstone%287cc2e828-2b0f-4cb7-a169-337193b854b8%29/publications.html) will likely be an interesting resource.

Answer (score 5):

The best description I have ever seen, with pictures illustrating each step of the algorithm, is contained in this book:

http://books.google.ca/books?id=05xA_d5dSwAC&lpg=PA381&dq=generalized%20deterministic%20parsers&pg=PA381#v=onepage&q=generalized%20deterministic%20parsers&f=false

For pseudocode, go to the source: Generalized LR Parsing by Tomita, page 70 or so. Farshi's paper contains a compact description.

http://books.google.ca/books?id=PvZiZiVqwHcC&lpg=PP1&dq=generalized%20lr%20parsing&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=&f=false

It's one of the techniques I tried for qb.js ([qbasic in javascript](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=92)).

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm aware, it functions the same as an LALR parser - except when it encounters an ambiguity.

When it does, it essentially divides into separate parses corresponding to the possible options at that point, and continues with them in tandem - when a parse fails (due to encountering an illegal element), it is simply dropped, because it must have been a wrong guess at an earlier ambiguity.

At the end, all but one parse should have died - and the surviving one is the "correct" parse of those ambiguous points.

Comment: Is it really as simple as that? Or are there specific alternative GLR algorithms out there?

Comment: That's basically it from my reading of the Bison manual (http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#GLR-Parsers) - it's actually pretty clear on how GLR parsers work.

Comment: You might find it a bit more complicated than this.

Comment: yeah, having read one of the papers @Matthew Slattery recommended, I do think the algorithm is rather more involved than that :)